# no any "plugin descriptor" founded in my maven project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, qt-jambi

I am wanting to create UI with qt-jambi, but i have a problem.
i am using maven in eclipse, and create a maven project, and i downloaded and installed 3rd party qt-jambi jar files in my local repository from here:
http://old.qt-jambi.org/maven2/net/sf/qtjambi/
and below files:

(1) [qtjambi-maven-plugin-linux32-4.5.2_01.jar](http://old.qt-jambi.org/maven2/net/sf/qtjambi/qtjambi-maven-plugin-linux32/4.5.2_01/)

(2) [qtjambi-platform-linux32-4.5.2_01.jar](http://old.qt-jambi.org/maven2/net/sf/qtjambi/qtjambi-platform-linux32/4.5.2_01/)

i am using ubuntu 12.10(32bit) and Maven 3.0.4.

My maven repository(m2 home)path for qt-jambi is like below:

```
/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/net/sf/qtjambi/qtjambi/4.5.2_01/qtjambi-4.5.2_01.jar
/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/net/sf/qtjambi/qtjambi-maven-plugin-linux32/4.5.2_01/qtjambi-maven-plugin-linux32-4.5.2_01.jar
```

so i add this lines to my pom.xml: http://old.qt-jambi.org/users/maven-repository/

my pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.iyasin</groupId>
  <artifactId>iycTest</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>iycTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.qtjambi</groupId>
        <artifactId>qtjambi</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2_01</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
            <groupId>net.sf.qtjambi</groupId>
            <artifactId>qtjambi-maven-plugin-linux32</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>qtjambi</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <sourcesDir>src/main/java</sourcesDir>
                <noObsoleteTranslations>true</noObsoleteTranslations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and when run `mvn test` or `mvn compile` return me below error:

```
 Failed to parse plugin descriptor for net.sf.qtjambi:qtjambi-maven-plugin-linux32:4.5.2_01 (/home/mehdi/.m2/repository/net/sf/qtjambi/qtjambi-maven-plugin-linux32/4.5.2_01/qtjambi-maven-plugin-linux32-4.5.2_01.jar): No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: You shouldn't download them manually let maven do that job...Correctly configure the repository...Take a look into the settings.xml documentation http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories

Comment: @khmarbaise tnx, this error (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository

Answer (score 0):

You need to add into the relevant part of your POM:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>qtjambi-releases-before-2011</id>
        <name>QtJambi (Releases Before 2011)</name>
        <url>http://repository.qt-jambi.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-before-2011</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

The above can be put into your settings.xml or project POM.

You should really run a local repository proxy (such as Nexus or Artifactory).  Then setup your settings.xml to point to that local repository.  Then configure it to cache central and qtjambi and other repositories you use.  However that benefits of this are too long to go into here, best to research the topic with google.